# Call Function PREG_REPLACE

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

With security and also a deprecated function; what would be the easiest and most secure way to call a function in a find and replace?

There are four find and replace modules which can be inserted within content `[album][/album], [img][/img], [youtube][/youtube], or [vimeo][/vimeo]`.

Using the function I put together so far Images, YouTube and Vimeo were a no brainer. The Album no so much. I would like to call a function based on parameters that are passed.

I tried altering this function into a `preg_replace_callback` and that just mocks up everything. Is there any alternatives?

```
function FormatModules($text) {
    $find = array(
        '~\[album\](.+?)\[/album\]~s',
        '~\[img width=(.*?) height=(.*?) alt=(.*?)\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))\[/img\]~s',
        '~\[youtube\](.+?)\[/youtube\]~s',
        '~\[vimeo\](.+?)\[/vimeo\]~s'
    );
    $replace = array(
        'GenerateAlbum($1)', // call a PHP function
        '<img src="$4" width="$1" height="$2" alt="$3" />',
        '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1"></iframe>',
        '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/$1"></iframe>'
    );
    return preg_replace($find, $replace, $text);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `preg_replace_callback` what went wrong? Can you show the code where you tried to use `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Run the rest as normal, run the album one by itself using the callback method.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to call a function on more than one replacement or you wish to set up your script for future modifications so that functions can be called on the replacement parameter, you might entertain [preg_replace_callback_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback-array.php).

Otherwise, I'd say make a `preg_replace_callback()` involving the first elements of `$find` and `$replace` then run a call of `preg_replace()` on the remaining elements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rckMt))

```
function GenerateAlbum($match) {
    return "<div class=\"album\>Do whatever: " . strtoupper($match[1]) . "</div>";
}

function FormatModules($text) {
    $text = preg_replace_callback('~\[album\](.+?)\[/album\]~s', "GenerateAlbum", $text);
    $find = array(
        '~\[img width=(.*?) height=(.*?) alt=(.*?)\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))\[/img\]~s',
        '~\[youtube\](.+?)\[/youtube\]~s',
        '~\[vimeo\](.+?)\[/vimeo\]~s'
    );
    $replace = array(
        '<img src="$4" width="$1" height="$2" alt="$3" />',
        '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1"></iframe>',
        '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/$1"></iframe>'
    );
    return preg_replace($find, $replace, $text);
}

echo FormatModules("[vimeo]test1[/vimeo]\n\n[album]test2[/album]\n\njust text\n\n[img width=50 height=100 alt='sumpin good']http://www.example.com/image.gif[/img]\n\n[youtube]test3[/youtube]");
```

Output:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/test1"></iframe>

<div class="album\>Do whatever: TEST2</div>

just text

<img src="http://www.example.com/image.gif" width="50" height="100" alt="'sumpin good'" />

<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/test3"></iframe>
```